# Delete and select operation in one transaction

Tags: java, database, transactions

Hi, I Have a transaction in  which I am deleting some rows from the table based on the given data and then I am doing a select query for the same data on the same table.I tried that and it is happening successfully.But if go by the transaction logic when we try to do delete operation at that point of time a lock will be applied on the table and therefore one might not be able to read the same data from the table unless the transaction is committed. So I want to know that is this kind of scenario valid or there is some mistake in my understanding.

The body inside the function follows this sequence :

```
public void method(){

//transaction starts

// delete operation on table 1

// select operation on table 1

// transaction is committed. 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There won't be any problem deleting and then selecting data *in the context of the same transaction*.

You may need to take locking into account if there are multiple concurrent transactions working with the same data. The exact mechanics depend on what the transactions are doing, the DBMS engine, transaction isolation level etc.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what database you are using but the below should be general and common.

If your method uses the same connection for the delete and the select, from your connection's context (point of view) the delete has happened so your query "for the same data on the same table" will return no records.

From all other concurrent connections (including your method if it is not using the same connection for the delete and select), your work is not committed and so depending on the technology and settings they ***may*** be blocked from even looking until you roll back or commit OR they may see a version of the data that is prior to your transaction beginning.